# How to configure Search refiners to display Managed Metadata columns? Is Managed Metadata supported as a refiner?

Tags: 2013, search, managed-metadata, sharepoint-server

[image]

I have a column in one list. The column's title is "Departments" and it is of type "Managed Metadata". I want this "Departments" column to show as a refiner on my default search results page. We are NOT using a search center,
 we are just using the OOTB search provided for a standard team site. So I navigate to "Site Settings > Search Schema > Managed Properties" I then find "RefinableString00" and map it to "ows_taxId_Departments". (I learn how
 to get this far from ready blog post) So let's push the pause button for a second. The prefix "ows_taxId_" designates this column as a Managed metadata column. "RefinableString" is of type "Text". There are no "RefinableString"
 Managed metadata Properties of type "Managed Metadata".

That makes me a little suspicious that what I'm trying to do is not supported. But moving along anyway. I got to my page and navigate to the search refiner web part. I edited the web part and choose the refiner I created in the previous step. But as you
 can set the Managed Metadata shows in the refiner as GUID text and not the department names. So, Is Managed Metadata supported as a search refiner? If so, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Instead of `ows_taxId_Departments` crawled property , use the `ows_Departments` property. Map it to another refiner called RefinableString01 and check

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Managed Metadata is supported as a refiner.

If you notice, there will 2 crawled properties created, namely `ows_Departments` and `ows_taxId_Departments`. The `ows_Departments` property contains all property values that the crawler finds, namely actual department values. This is the property you should use and map to a Refiner. For now, map it to new `RefinableString01` and use that in your webpart.

The crawled property beginning with `ows_taxId` hold values which are read from the term store. It holds internal values which shows up as gibberish to us.